# Scale an image to fit some maximum dimension using vanilla JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

> Fill in the ? with a Javascript expression to set the scale ratio for
>   an image having a given height and width so that it fit inside a
>   maxdim-by-maxdim square area (touching at least two edges).
>
> ```
> function scaleImage(width, height, maxdim) {
>   var scale = ?;
>   return [scale * width, scale * height];
> }
> ```

Here is my solution:

```
function scaleImage(width, height, maxdim) {
  var scale = (width > height ? maxdim/width : maxdim/height);
  return [scale * width, scale * height];
}
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: Working code generally belongs on the code review stack exchange :)

Comment: CSS would be more efficient, unless you intend on intentionally stretching the image to larger than its natural aspect ratio. `img { max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%; height: auto; width: auto; }`

Comment: @Herohtar Can you make this the answer and I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would probably use [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max), as that seems more readable to me and would make what is happening more clear. However, I don't think it will affect efficiency in any meaningful way since it's still making a comparison to determine the max.

```
var scale = maxdim / Math.max(width, height);
```